# switch case javascript (tem como simplificar esse código)

Tags: javascript

gostaria de saber se tem como simplificar de alguma maneira esse código...
no exemplo do 1 ao 7 quero o mesmo resultado mas até ai são poucos mas... e se fossem muitos números teria como não ter que colocar tantos cases ou seria melhor usar if mesmo?

```
let codigo = 7;
switch(codigo){
    case 1:
    case 2: 
    case 3: 
    case 4:
    case 5:
    case 6:
    case 7: 
        console.log("Acertou");
        break;
    case 8:
        console.log("Poderia ser mas... não é.");
        break;
    default:
        console.log("Tente mais tarde");
        break;

}
```

Comment: Tem como simplificar esse código !!! até tem, nesse contexto um `if` na minha opinião é melhor, agora se for muitos ... geralmente o código tem algo que a gente não sabe, talvez com comparação.

Comment: eu faço com pathern test de regex, fica bem pequeno

Answer (score 3):

Neste caso eu não usaria o `switch`. Você poderia simplificar com a ajuda de um vetor ou um simples if, dependendo do caso. Veja:

Com vetor:

```
let accepted_answers = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7];
let maybe = [8]
let answer= 8;

if(accepted_answers.indexOf(answer) !== -1){
    console.log("Acertou");
}else if(maybe.indexOf(answer) !== -1){
    console.log("Poderia ser mas... não é.");
}else{
    console.log("Tente mais tarde");
}
```

Apenas if:

```
let answer = 7;

if(answer >= 1 && answer <= 7){
   console.log("Acertou");
}else if(answer === 8){
   console.log("Poderia ser mas... não é.");
}else{
   console.log("Tente mais tarde");
}
```

Eu particularmente usaria vetores por ter mais flexibilidade e possibilidade de montar o vetor de respostas aceitas de forma mais dinâmica sem precisar ficar voltando ao código.

Um ponto mais sobre o indexOf:

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_indexof_array.asp

https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf

Comment: mais ai você teria que criar um vetor com várias posições? é inviável !

Comment: @VirgilioNovic depende do contexto. Eu baseei o codigo nas informações da pergunta. Eu poderia por exemplo, ter este vetor pronto armazenado em um banco de dados e seria perfeitamente viável.

Comment: se vier do banco pode ser feita na SQL essa comparação, claro se tiver controle para tal, se vir de um API pode fazer um indexOf porque o `array` já está pronto, mas, se for pra você fazer é inviável.